# when am connecting to my server using filezilla it brings this error

Tags: windows, router, firefox

```
Status: Resolving address of ftp.ewemwa.org
Status: Connecting to 192.185.115.188:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Initializing TLS...
Status: Verifying certificate...
Status: TLS connection established.
Command:    USER ewemwa.org
Response:   331 User ewemwa.org OK. Password required
Command:    PASS *************
Response:   530 Login authentication failed
Error:  Critical error: Could not connect to server
Status: Disconnected from server
Status: Resolving address of ftp.ewemwa.org
Status: Connecting to 192.185.115.188:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Initializing TLS...
Status: Verifying certificate...
Status: TLS connection established.
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is your current location
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (192,185,115,188,132,70)
Command:    MLSD
Response:   150 Accepted data connection
Response:   421 chdir: Permission denied
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
Error:  GnuTLS error -110 in gnutls_record_recv: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
Status: Server did not properly shut down TLS connection
Error:  Could not read from socket: ECONNABORTED - Connection aborted
Error:  Disconnected from server
Status: Resolving address of ftp.ewemwa.org
Status: Connecting to 192.185.115.188:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Initializing TLS...
Status: Verifying certificate...
Status: TLS connection established.
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is your current location
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (192,185,115,188,195,68)
Command:    MLSD
Response:   150 Accepted data connection
Response:   421 chdir: Permission denied
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
Error:  GnuTLS error -110: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
Status: Server did not properly shut down TLS connection
Status: Disconnected from server: ECONNABORTED - Connection aborted
Status: Disconnected from server
Status: Resolving address of ftp.ewemwa.org
Status: Connecting to 192.185.115.188:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Initializing TLS...
Status: Verifying certificate...
Status: TLS connection established.
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing of "/"...
Command:    CWD /
Response:   550 Can't change directory to /: Permission denied
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
Status: Disconnected from server
Status: Resolving address of ftp.ewemwa.org
Status: Connecting to 192.185.115.188:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Initializing TLS...
Status: Verifying certificate...
Status: TLS connection established.
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing of "/"...
Command:    CWD /
Response:   550 Can't change directory to /: Permission denied
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is your current location
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (192,185,115,188,152,114)
Command:    MLSD
Response:   150 Accepted data connection
Response:   421 chdir: Permission denied
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
Error:  GnuTLS error -110: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
Status: Server did not properly shut down TLS connection
Status: Disconnected from server: ECONNABORTED - Connection aborted
```

Comment: Please spend some time reading [how to ask a good question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask). You didn't even include your question in your body of the message. That said the 550 response tells you what your problem is (likely).

Answer (score 0):

Your server does not allow access to the `/` directory:

```
Response:   550 Can't change directory to /: Permission denied
```

There are two likely causes for this:

- Judging by the IP behind the hostname, it seems the FTP service is provided by a hosting provider. Did you follow their instructions on how to use their FTP service? You might need to access a directory like `/users/username/web` or something.
- Since you specifically said it is *your* server: In that case I would assume your user account has the right filesystem permissions to access `/`. In that case, most probably this is a configuration error in the FTP service. The FTP service log should provide more insight and it is impossible to address this issue without knowing which software the server is using.